# Binding nested objects with a string key

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have a project that generates forms based on the data that is passed in.

We support may field types but, for example, here is the `input` template:

```
<label>
    {{fieldSchema.label}}
    <input type="{{fieldSchema.attributes.type}}"
           name="{{fieldSchema.attributes.name}}"
           ng-model="model[ fieldSchema.attributes.name ]" />
</label>
```

This works great for flat models, however if the model is nested, it falls apart, eg:

```
$scope.model = {
    manager: {
        first_name: 'John'
    }
}
$scope.fieldSchema.attributes.name = 'manager.first_name';
```

Is there a way to use `$parse` or `$interpolate` or something similar within the `ng-model`? I've seen examples on how to *fetch* data in this structure, but I haven't been able to find a two-way binding solution.

(Note: Using angular version 1.5.0)

**Edit:** Here is a plunk, hopefully this makes it more clear.  http://plnkr.co/edit/4E8jlsnuy5HkCZPxSf5z?p=preview

Comment: may I know how your input `template` is getting rendered?

Comment: I'm fetching an HTML template (based on what's in `fieldSchema`), and using `element.html( html );`

Comment: Not clear at all what specific problem is. A demo would help

Comment: Can you "touch" the model? (Keep the current structure, but add some features)

Comment: @MattGrande it would be great if you could add `fiddle/plunkr` of problem statement..

Comment: @charlietfl: Since the `ng-model` is bound to `model[ fieldSchema.attributes.name ]`, it's expect the data to be in `model[ 'manager.first_name ' ]`, rather than `model.manager.first_name`. Is that clearer?

Comment: @Amit: Yes, I can do that.

Comment: Added a plunkr. Hopefully that helps?

Comment: How about using `ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }"`?

Comment: Actually, why not simply prepend `fieldSchema.attributes.name` with `'model.'`?

Comment: @Amit that would be really good idea.. most shorter version to achieve it..

Comment: Amit, I ended up using `ng-model-options`, as that resulted in the fewest changes to other parts of the app. Thanks! If you add that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: I'm on mobile and can't post a complex answer, but post the answer yourself so that others can use it in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up doing what Amit suggested in the comments. Thanks, Amit!

First, I created a getter/setter function in my directive:

```
function getterSetter( newValue ) {

     var getter = $parse( 'model.' + $scope.wxFormField.attributes.name ),
         setter = getter.assign;

     return arguments.length ? setter( $scope, newValue ) : getter( $scope );
}
```

Then, I changed the `ng-model` to a that function, and added the `ng-model-options` directive.

```
<label>
    {{fieldSchema.label}}
    <input type="{{fieldSchema.attributes.type}}"
           name="{{fieldSchema.attributes.name}}"
           ng-model="formFieldFunctions.getterSetter"
           ng-model-options="{ getterSetter: true }" />
</label>
```

Answer (score 1):

If template input template `html` can be controlled  by code, then before rendering/appending html to DOM do manipulate, it in below way.

```
ng-model="model[fieldSchema.attributes.name]"
```

to

```
ng-model="model['manager']['first_name']"
```

**Code**

```
function createNgModel(model){
   var values = model.split('.')
   //and then create a format it do have below format
   //model['manager']['first_name']
};

var template = '<label>'+
    '{{fieldSchema.label}}'+
    '<input type="{{fieldSchema.attributes.type}}"'+
           'name="{{fieldSchema.attributes.name}}"'+
           'ng-model="+ createNgModel(fieldSchema.attributes.name) +" />'+
'</label>';
```

Or rather a good option would be just append the string value returned by `fieldSchema.attributes.name` as suggested by @Amit in comments

```
var template = '<label>'+
    '{{fieldSchema.label}}'+
    '<input type="{{fieldSchema.attributes.type}}"'+
           'name="{{fieldSchema.attributes.name}}"'+
           'ng-model="model.'+ fieldSchema.attributes.name+'" />'+
'</label>';
```

Comment: That works for one field, but I have dozens, in an `ng-repeat` and not all of them are under the `manager` field.

Comment: Oh, I see what you're saying... I'd rather not move all of my templates into the directive, but I suppose that's an option.

Comment: @MattGrande look at the updated answer...as per Amit's comment